# Adding a class to a div when condition satifies with jsrender

Tags: javascript, css, jsrender

I can't figure out how to add a `class` to a `div` when a condition is satisfied. What are my options here?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div class="wbackground rfonts {{if data.isPerson}}person{{else if data.isCat}}cat{{/if}}">

    ...

</div>
```

So far I've tried using the `if` tag inside the `class` attribute and it just doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JsViews - i.e. you are doing data-linking (dynamic data-binding of UI to data), calling the `link()` method, then see here http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link for a whole tutorial sequence of samples on data-linking elements, which actually starts out from a plain JsRender sample that includes

`<span class="{{if role.indexOf('Lead')>=0}}special{{/if}}">`.

So note that that syntax is totally allowed when just using JsRender, with the `render()` method.

However if you want to use data-linking, then the samples show you how to do that, including this specific sample for linking class: http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/class and this one for toggling class:  http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/toggle.

If you are just using JsRender (calling the `render()` method, not the `link()` method) then see also http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag which explains all about how to use `{{if}} ... {{else ...}} {{else}} ... {{/if}}`.

Comment: Just read the tutorial on data-link again and took a closer look on the 'merge' converter, which does exactly what I want! However, when I try to use it I get this error: `Uncaught JsRender Error: Unknown converter: {{merge: `

Comment: BorisMoore, I'm using the following version of jsViews (downloaded it with bower): `"jsviews": "~1.0.0-alpha"` Don`t know if it has got anything to do with the above error... I'm copy-pasting from the sample, so everything in the data-link declaration looks fine

Comment: BorisMoore Looking into the code of the published version in `bower` I found out that there is no definition for `$converter.merge` which is what is causing my problem. The documentation code works only because it fetches JsViews from this url: http://www.jsviews.com/download/jsviews.js.

Comment: Yes, you need to get the latest version. That feature was added subsequently to the labelled alpha. Things have moved quite a bit since the alpha, so the new code is better. jsviews.com/download/jsviews.js will always give you the latest - so including any new features or bug fixes...

Comment: Thanks @BorisMoore! Is managed to pull the latest version from master using `bower` with the following syntax: 

"jsviews": "https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews.git#master" 

That will allways pull the code from the last commit in `master`, which is "stable" I hope

Comment: Yes, that should be stable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `if` and a `else`. The `else` will wokrs like a `elseif`. The code comes below:

```
<div class="wbackground rfonts {{if data.isPerson}}person{{else data.isCat}}cat{{/if}}">
```

If need more reference take a look at the documentation here: http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag

Just to make more clear this explanation try to change to true/false the value in the else(elseif) sequence below:

```
{{if b1}}person{{else b2}}cat1{{else b3}}cat2{{/if}}
```

Below follow the boolean parameters combination:

```
   b1=true, b2=true,b3=true => "person"
   b1=false, b2=true,b3=true => "cat1"
   b1=false, b2=false,b3=true => "cat2"
   b1=false, b2=false,b3=false => ""
```

`Else` works like a normal else too, without any boolean parameter.

Comment: I get this error:  JsRender Error: Syntax error
Unmatched or missing tag: "{{/if}}" ... Seems like jsrender doesn't like using the if statement with the class attribute :/

Comment: Man, sorry by my last tip.. Now I found the answer reading this page https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/138 . The thing is `else` works at same time a common `else` and as a `elseif` but in both cases you need to use `else`. I updated now the code, enjoy!

Comment: "... If you try that (using the Try it button, for example) you will see that it renders incorrectly. Putting JsRender tags like {{if}} within an HTML element tag, including within an attribute value is an example of invalid JsViews template markup. For details on the rules for what is valid, or invalid, within a JsViews template see the JsViews API topic: JsViews template tags." Took this from here: http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/class, tutorial which by the way followed and didn't help.

Comment: Daniel, are you using JsViews - calling the link() method, or just JsRender - calling the render() method. If you are just rendering, not data-linking (binding) then using {{if data.isPerson}}person{{else data.isCat}}cat{{/if}} within the HTML element tag is valid and will work. But if you are using link() then it is invalid, and that tutorial is the right approach. Which are you using?

Comment: @BorisMoore, I'm using JsViews calling the link() method